# Anchor #link on the same page to a Woocommerce jQuery tab

Tags: jquery, tabs

*Sort of a jQuery newbie here.*

I'm trying to set up an anchor tag to a tab, like this:

```
<a href="#tab-ebook_tab">E-books</a>
```

The anchor tag is on the same page as the tabs; I don't need to use a URL hash #.

The tab markup is below. The page loads with the first tab `#tab-reviews` active.

```
<div class="woocommerce-tabs">
<ul class="tabs">           
        <li class="reviews_tab">
            <a href="#tab-reviews">Reader Comments</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stories_tab_tab">
            <a href="#tab-stories_tab">More Stories</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ebook_tab_tab">
            <a href="#tab-ebook_tab">E-book</a>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is the function I'm trying to use with the anchor tag to scroll to and open the `#tab-ebook_tab` location.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery( '#tab-ebook_tab' ).show();
   jQuery( 'li.tab-ebook_tab a' ).trigger('click');
});
```

But, it only works when the `#tab-ebook_tab` is already open; then the anchor tag `<a href="#tab-ebook_tab">E-books</a>` will fire and the page will scroll down to the `#tab-ebook_tab` tab.

No errors show in the console. jQuery v2.0.3 is loaded.

Other questions and answers here in SO deal with URL hashes and off page links. Appending `#tab-ebook_tab` to the page URL doesn't open the tab or scroll to it; but I don't need that. I only need to link from the same page, not a full URL from another page.

Comment: Something in your above jQuery looks slightly off. Specifically, the `('li.tab-ebook_tab a')` selector wouldn't work because there's actually no <li> with class 'tab-ebook_tab'. I think you meant to write 'li.ebook_tab_tab' so when it's fully written, I think it should be `jQuery('li.ebook_tab_tab a').trigger('click');`

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but no go. BTW, I'm asking here as no one in the Woocommerce forums knew how to do it....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you have a woocomerce tab on the page initialized and working properly. Now you want to have some links on the same page which takes user to the particular tab and also scroll the page to bring the tab in view. Let me know, if I misunderstood the scenario.

**Solution**

This solution opens up the Ebook tab and scrolls it in view.

**HTML :**

Create links anywhere on the page which takes user to a particular woocomerce tab. This link will have a special class and will have the same href value as the first anchor in the  tab (to be directed) has. I'm using `switchtab` as the anchor class here :

```
<a class="switchtab" href="#tab-ebook_tab">Open ebook tab</a>
```

**jQuery :**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("a.switchtab").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //Prevents hash to be appended at the end of the current URL.
        $("div.woocommerce-tabs>ul.tabs>li>a[href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "']").click(); //Opens up the particular tab
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("div.woocommerce-tabs").offset().top
        }, 1000); //Change to whatever you want, this value is in milliseconds.
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice, works perfectly. Even Woocommerce support didn't have an answer for this. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why this excellent piece of code does not work on mobile devices?

Comment: That may be due to click event binding on mobile, try this in place of Click event and bind the click and touchstart...


$(document).on('touchstart click', 'a.switchtab', function(event){

Answer (score 2):

It was a bit hard to understand exactly what is needed. But Below is the jQuery code which I believe is the answer to your question.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.ebook_tab_tab').on('click', function () {
        jQuery('#tab-ebook_tab').trigger('click');
        jQuery('#tab-ebook_tab').attr('style', 'display:block;');
        jQuery('#tab-reviews').attr('style', 'display:none;');

    });

});
```

Also here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/visvam07/nafvqfyg/) that I played with. I hope this is a starting point!!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are asking here, Is this the kind of functionality you're after [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/VM48K/3/)

```
//animate to ebooks and show ebook content
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#id-tab-ebook_tab").offset().top
   }, 1000, function () {
       console.log("Animating");
   }).promise().done($('#id-tab-ebook_tab').trigger('click'));
```

Comment: Hmmmm.... that doesn't do anything other than scroll the page. I need the link <a href="#tab-ebook_tab">E-books</a> to open the #tab-ebook_tab tab

Comment: Did you try something along these lines `window.location = $('#tab-ebook_tab').attr('href');`  ?